# I am appending a footer to a dialog, how to fix the height?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am appending a footer to the jquery ui dialog, and the footer style is just like the header i.e. it is fixed at the bottom, so if there is a scroll the content won't move the footer on the bottom.

The problem is, the height that the dialog automatically calculates is wrong because I am appending the footer html to the dialog, and I'm guessing this is AFTER it calculates the height, therefore the footer is in front of the text content.

So I am doing:

```
var footer = "<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" ... ";

$("#popup").dialog({
   modal: true,
   autoOpen: false,
   auto: true
}).parent().append(footer);

// if condition here
$("#popup").dialog("open");
```

So I copied the style that the header has for my footer.

In chrome/firefox, I added this option to the dialog which adjusted the hieight by 20px which fixed my issue:

```
$("#popup").dialog({
 modal: true,
 autoOpen: false,
 auto: true,
 open = function() {
   $("#popup").css('height', $("#popup").height() + 20);
  }

});
```

Ideally I want to add the footer content to the dialog before it calculates the height, or somehow tell it to re-calculate the height.

The problem is, calling .dialog is what adds all the html/css/styling to the element #popup, and after the call (which calculates the height) I chain the append call but by that time it is too late.

Can I fix this somehow?  Again, **it has to work in IE**.

Comment: Which versions of IE does it have to work in?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `create` method instead of `open`.  When I do that this works fine for me in Chrome & IE 7 - 9.

**Example** - http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/PUttC/.